# Regular expression to match C's multiline preprocessor statements

Tags: python, regex

what I need is to match multiline preprocessor's statements such as:

```
#define max(a,b) \
       ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
           typeof (b) _b = (b); \
         _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

The point is to match everything between `#define` and last `})`, but I still can't figure out how to write the regexp. I need it to make it work in Python, using "re" module.

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What regex flavor are you working with?

Comment: I need it to make it work in Python's script, using "re" module...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
r'(?m)^#define (?:.*\\\r?\n)*.*$'
```

`(?:.*\\\r?\n)*` matches zero or more lines ending with backslashes, then `.*$` matches the final line.

Comment: Under-appreciated answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work:

```
m = re.compile(r"^#define[\s\S]+?}\)*$", re.MULTILINE)
matches = m.findall(your_string_here)
```

This assumes that your macros all end with '}', with an optional ')' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think above solution might not work for:

```
#define MACRO_ABC(abc, djhg) \
do { \
  int i; \
  /*
   * multi line comment 
   */ \
  (int)i; \
} while(0);
```

Comment: could you please explain ab bit what the code actually does?